# What is the difference between obj[name] and obj['name'] in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, oop, object, key

I have an Object 'Obj' with property name.

```
var Obj = {name: "NamePropertyValue", '': "EmptyPropertyValue", null: 'NullPropertyValue'}

console.log(Obj["name"]);  >>> Output is : NamePropertyValue

console.log(Obj["null"]);  >>> Output is : NullPropertyValue
console.log(Obj[null]);  >>> Output is : NullPropertyValue
```

But for below case output is EmptyPropertyValue and not NamePropertyValue. **WHY?**

```
console.log(Obj[name]);  >>> Output is : EmptyPropertyValue
```

**What is 'name' in Javascript?Why by default it has empty string value and not 'undefined'**

```
var abc;    
console.log(abc);  >>> undefined
var name;
console.log(name);  >>>      (it gives empty string and not undefined. Why?)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is the difference between obj[name] and obj['name'] in JavaScript

`name` is a variable. `'name'` is a string.

The value between the square brackets is always evaluated as a string.

```
var name = "name";
Obj[name] === Obj["name"]

var name = "other";
Obj[name] !== Obj["name"]
```

> What is 'name' in Javascript?Why by default it has empty string value and not 'undefined'

It is the [name of the window](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/name).

Answer (score 1):

Well, if we use name in global context this will be equal to `name === window.name`

[read more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/name)

Whereas here `obj['name'] === obj.name` we are accessing property using bracket notation if there is defined one inside `obj` with empty string as key otherwise value will be `undefined`. So, question remains why does then when we use name inside object bracket notation
**doesn't produce error instead is equal to** `name === ''` say if we use 'game' rather than 'name' this happens because of how Global Object work in JavaScript
[read more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Global_object) in short because there is a property named name inside window object that is why when we define this JavaScript will look first inside script if there is any variable name defined if not it will go global object in this case window.